# Powershell binary module: Dynamic tab completion for Cmdlet parameter values

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module

I'm writing a binary Powershell module in C# and I'd like to have a Cmdlet with a parameter that provides dynamic, run-time tab completion. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this in a binary module. Here's my attempt to get this working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace DynamicParameterCmdlet
{

    [Cmdlet("Say", "Hello")]
    public class MyCmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {

        [Parameter, PSTypeName("string")]
        public RuntimeDefinedParameter Name { get; set; }

        public MyCmdlet() : base() {
            Collection<Attribute> attributes = new Collection<Attribute>() {
                new ParameterAttribute()
            };

            string[] allowedNames = NameProvider.GetAllowedNames();
            attributes.Add(new ValidateSetAttribute(allowedNames));
            Name = new RuntimeDefinedParameter("Name", typeof(string), attributes);
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            string name = (string)Name.Value;
            WriteObject($"Hello, {Name}");
        }
    }

    public static class NameProvider
    {
        public static string[] GetAllowedNames()
        {
            // Hard-coded array here for simplicity but imagine in reality this
            // would vary at run-time
            return new string[] { "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie" };
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I don't get any tab completion functionality. I also get an error:

```
PS > Say-Hello -Name Alice
Say-Hello : Cannot bind parameter 'Name'. Cannot convert the "Alice" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter".
At line:1 char:17
+ Say-Hello -Name Alice
+                 ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Say-Hello], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,DynamicParameterCmdlet.MyCmdlet
```

I've found [an article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pstips/archive/2014/06/10/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter.aspx) with an example of how to do it in a non-binary Powershell module. It seems in non-binary modules you include `DynamicParam` followed by statements that build and return a `RuntimeParameterDictionary` object. Based on this examplem I would at expect the equivalent in the `PSCmdlet` class, perhaps an overridable `GetDynamicParameters()` method or something similiar, just as there is an overridable `BeginProcessing()` method.

At this rate, binary modules are looking to be second-class citizens in the Powershell world. Surely there is a way to do this that I've missed?

Comment: I believe at a minimum you need to add the [IDynamicParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.idynamicparameters(v=vs.85).aspx) interface to your cmdlet to use dynamic parameters. From there I believe you do that same thing as you have in the example (create a RuntimeParameterDictionary, etc) however I cannot confirm this.

Comment: [IDynamicParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.idynamicparameters(v=vs.85).aspx) will let you determine the parameters at runtime, but I believe the OP is asking about providing dynamic parameter _values_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a way how you can implement custom argument completer in PowerShell v5:

```
Add-Type @‘
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.Management.Automation.Language;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test,"Completion")]
    public class TestCompletionCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
        private string name;
        [Parameter,ArgumentCompleter(typeof(NameCompleter))]
        public string Name {
            set {
                name=value;
            }
        }
        protected override void BeginProcessing() {
            WriteObject(string.Format("Hello, {0}", name));
        }
        private class NameCompleter : IArgumentCompleter {
            IEnumerable<CompletionResult> IArgumentCompleter.CompleteArgument(string commandName,
                                                                              string parameterName,
                                                                              string wordToComplete,
                                                                              CommandAst commandAst,
                                                                              IDictionary fakeBoundParameters) {
                return GetAllowedNames().
                       Where(new WildcardPattern(wordToComplete+"*",WildcardOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch).
                       Select(s => new CompletionResult(s));
            }
            private static string[] GetAllowedNames() {
                return new string[] { "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie" };
            }
        }
    }
’@ -PassThru|Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Assembly|Import-Module
```

In particular, you need:

- Implement `IArgumentCompleter` interface. Class implementing this interface should have public default constructor.
- Apply `ArgumentCompleterAttribute` attribute to property of field, used as cmdlet parameter. As parameter to attribute, you should pass `IArgumentCompleter` implementation.
- In `IArgumentCompleter.CompleteArgument` you have `wordToComplete` parameter, so you can filter completion options by text, already inputted by user.

And to try it:

```
Test-Completion -Name Tab
```

Comment: I had to install the Windows Management Framework 5.0 preview, but once I did it actually work! Thanks very much!